# Unable to write into user settings. Please open the user settings to correct errors/warnings in it and try again

Tags: json, visual-studio, visual-studio-code

I am aware that there are some similar questions on this website with similar errors. However, it seems as if this error is different from person to person and I don't quite know how to solve it.

I get that error and when I open the settings in vs code, I have this:

```
{
    "files.autoSave": "afterDelay",
    "editor.formatOnPaste": true,
    "editor.formatOnSave": true
    "terminal.integrated.shellArgs.windows": [
        "-ExecutionPolicy",
        "Bypass"
    ]
}
```

VS Code is saying that there is an error from the fifth line (starting with: "terminal....") until the end. When I hover my mouse over the error, it says:

`The command line arguments to use when on the Windows terminal. Read more about configuring the shell.`

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: You need a comma after the `true`  before the `terminal` line.

Comment: @Mark That solved it! Thank you so much